# ¿Cómo sustituyo los saltos de línea por comas en un fichero?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo este archivo "u.tmp":

```
1063242442
1068885759
1088045563
1088047175
1088048104
1091322429
1091323565
1091326033
```

Ahora quisiera ver que quede así:

```
1063242442,1068885759,1088045563,1088047175 etc..
```

Intento quitar los saltos de linea con un `"cat u.tmp | xargs"` y nada.

Intente también esto:

```
distros=$(cat u.tmp)

for i in "${distros[@]}"
do
  echo -n ",${i} " >> f.tmp
done
```

**EDIT**: Ya probe con la respuesta de abajo y funciona si pero para algunos archivos tengo el sguiente problema de cualquier forma les agradezco su tiempo

Generé este archivo 1.tmp

```
1083108343
1083108360
1083108378
1083108386
```

Le hago `"paste -s -d, - < 1.tmp"` y la SALIDA ES ERRONEA  sale esto

```
,1083108386
```

Como si solamente hubiera el ultimo elemento lo cheque con xxd y si tiene los caracteres de salto de linea (0d0a)
alguna idea de porque sucede esto ?

Comment: Existe un comando llamado *tr* con ese puedes eliminar los saltos de linea y reemplazarlos, incluso puedes hacerlo son *sed*.

Answer (score 2):

`tr` hace exactamente esto:

```
$ tr '\n' ',' < fichero
1063242442,1068885759,1088045563,1088047175,1088048104,1091322429,1091323565,1091326033,
```

Es decir, convierte cada salto de línea en una coma.

También tienes `paste`, al que le dices con `d` qué delimitador quieres usar para juntar:

```
$ paste -s -d, - < fichero
1063242442,1068885759,1088045563,1088047175,1088048104,1091322429,1091323565,1091326033
```

Lo bueno de este último es que no te queda una coma al final. Es decir, es lo suficientemente *inteligente* para ver que está juntando cachos y que el último no necesita incluir la coma.

Comment: Versión aún más corta: `paste -sd, < archivo`

Comment: Me parece que, por la respuesta que el mismo dueño del post se dió, podrías usar una variante: `$ tr -d "\r" < archivo | tr "\n" ","`

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a porque comandos como xargs paste tr no servian correctamente es
lo que sucedio.

Windows maneja los saltos de linea como 0d0a
Linux manejea solo con 0a los salto de linea

Por lo tanto si tienes un archivo txt con formato de windows pasale el "dos2unix" para quitar el 0d y solo deja los salto de linea en formato.Linux entiende el 0a nada mas y después de usar esta herramienta cualquier comando funciona :)

Espero le sirva a alguien que me lea un saludo

Comment: Yo poniendo mi respuesta pensando que los saltos de línea eran los típicos *LF* y apenas leyendo tu respuesta donde indicas que son *CRLF*

Answer (score 1):

### Usando `awk`

Puedes intentar con:

```
$ awk 1 ORS=, archivo
```

Y la variable `ORS`, que indica el separador de registros de salida, la definimos como una coma.

### Usando `IFS` y `readarray`

```
$ ( IFS=","; readarray -t ar < archivo; echo "${ar[*]}" )
```

Donde utilizamos una subshell para proteger la variable `IFS` que está en el nivel principal.

### Usando `sed`

Otro truco conocido es el de usar un loop de `sed`:

```
$ sed ':label1 ; N ; $! b label1; s/\n/,/g' archivo
```

Donde definimos un label de nombre *label1* con `:label1`, luego con `N` pegamos la linea anterior a la linea actual en el *pattern space*.

Luego, indicando con `$!`, indicamos que si no hemos llegado a la última línea entonces volvemos al *label1* con `b label1`, por lo que seguímos pegando la línea siguiente a las anteriores en el *pattern space*.

Al final nos tendrían que quedar pegadas todas la líneas en el *pattern space*. Después, con el comando `s/\n/,/g`, nos aseguramos de que todos los saltos de línea en el *pattern space* serán reemplazados por comas.

### Ahora con `perl`

También `perl` es de mucha ayuda:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n//' archivo
```

### Usando los *builtin* (herramientas incorporadas) de Bash

```
$ while read row; do printf "$row,"; done < archivo
```

### Utilizando `vim`

Entra a tu archivo con:

```
$ vim archivo
```

Luego presiona la tecla ESC para entrar a modo comandos.

Después escribe dos puntos `:`, es decir, en teclado latinoamericano, *shift + .*

Luego ingresamos el comando: `%s/\n/,/` y damos enter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Actualización

Debido a que no había leído tu propia respuesta, ahora sé que tu problema principal eran los saltos de línea de la forma CRLF de Windows.

Hay varios comandos que nos pueden ayudar en esto.

### Perl

```
$ perl -pe 's/[\n|\r]+/,/' archivo
```

### sed

```
$ sed -r ':label1;N;$!blabel1;s/[\n|\r]+/,/g' archivo
```

Y supongo que también se puede hacer una variante de lo de vim, pero se le queda de tarea al lector.